# hybridauth facebook and like gating

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-like, hybridauth

I'm setting the hybridauth to get it working with my login. All the standard things are working but I would like to use this library to check if a user has liked my facebook page. How can I do that using this library? 
Is there any one can point me in the right direction with some example?

Thank you

Comment: Like gating is not allowed any more by Facebook.

Comment: Ok I understand, but I suppose there is a way to know if someone has liked the facebook page and make a conditional statament based on that

Comment: Only if the user grants your app `user_likes` permission – and Facebook will not grant you that in review, if you are only using it to find out if the user liked a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid_Auth [API Doc](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/apidoc.html) available you can check the all options provided by hybrid auth, this can be fetch providing "scope"   => 'user_likes' in array. facebook hydrid auth example explained [here](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html)

You can get all the details information of facebook [Permissions details are available here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

facebook provides access to the list of all Facebook Pages and Open Graph objects that a person has liked. If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) how your app uses it.